# Does a Nigerian need a transit visa for a 14-hour layover in Panama, traveling from Camaroon to Barbados?

Tags: transit, transit-visas, nigerian-citizens, panama

I am traveling from Camaroon to Barbados.  I am Nigerian.  There is a 14 hour layover in Panama.  Can I bypass the transit visa requirement and stay in the airport terminal or the Copa Lounge?

Answer (score 6):

According to the [IATA](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm) a transit  greater than 12 hours requires a transit visa for Nigerian citizens (see below for screenshot). HOWEVER, you are exempt from this requirement if you have any of the multiple entry visas from the countries mentioned below (and in picture):

- Australia
- Canada
- Japan
- Korea (aka South Korea)
- Singapore
- USA
- UK
- any EU member state

[image: Nigeria Panamá here]

Comment: There is an additional factor which is whether it is feasible to spend 14 hours in Panama airport. It may close overnight.

Comment: @DJClayworth PTY does not close. There are departures until 22:30 ish at night, with a pause until 2am. But arrivals continue coming between those hours.