# Panama Transit Visa

Tags: transit, transit-visas, applications, nigerian-citizens, panama

I am a Nigeria citizen. I am trying to obtain a Panama transit visa, but they don't have an embassy here in Nigeria. Is there a way I can apply for it online?

Comment: How long is your transit? https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/181746/does-a-nigerian-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-14-hour-layover-in-panama-traveling-f

Comment: 14 hrs long. How can I apply for the transit visa required?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply for a Panama visa "online". There is an [online portal](http://sigob.mire.gob.pa/Consular/) offering this service from the Panamanian ministry of foreign affairs, BUT it is only available in Spanish. You would have to choose one of the three embassies on the African continent for processing of your application, and may have to end up going in person for biometrics or an interview. The three representations in your area are:

- Cairo, Egypt
- Casablanca, Morocco
- Pretoria, South Africa

Comment: Thanks for your response, very helpful. Sigh, this is a big task on my end, cos I reside in Nigeria, and I'm not sure if I will be able to appear in person for biometrics, thought it is an application that can be done online.

Comment: If you feel it answers your question then please accept it. I understand it isn't convenient , but you can always contact the consulates before applying to see if it can all be done remotely. Here is the link to the contact info of the embassy in Morocco (https://mire.gob.pa/ministerio/embajada-y-consulado/rabat-embajada/) you can find the others in the same page

Comment: Thanks for your responses. It really helps.